# efficient way to do 'contains' between two lists

Tags: java, collections, arraylist, time-complexity

I have 2 lists of integers,

```
l1 = new ArrayList();
l2 = new ArrayList();
```

I want to find out duplicate items in both of them, I have my usual approach:-

```
for (Integer i : l1)
{
 if(l2.contains(i)){
    System.out.println("Found!");
  } 
}
```

I've heard `contains()` is `O(n)`, making my implementation `O(n^2)`.

Is there a better way to do this, (less than `O(n^2)`) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure - create a `HashSet<Integer>` from one of the lists first.

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(l2);
for (Integer i : l1) {
    if (set.contains(i)) {
        System.out.println("Found!");
    }
}
```

If you want to find all duplicate entries, you don't even need to write your own loop, as `Set<E>` provides everything you need...

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(l2);
set.retainAll(new HashSet<Integer>(l1));
```

Afterwards, `set` will be the intersection of the two lists.

Note that you can be even more efficient than this if both your lists are already sorted to start with. You just iterate over both at the same time, moving the "cursor" forward for whichever iterator currently has the smaller value.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `set.contains(i)`?

Comment: @dlev: Yup, fixed. But there's a better approach to find the whole intersection - see my edited version...

Comment: Very nice. Hadn't seen `retainAll()` before. Assuming he just wants the duplicates (rather than acting on each one) that's way cleaner.

Comment: retainAll seems nice, but the previous loops is `o(n^2)` like mine. Can you explain the cursor solution? It seems like it'll be better ( `O(nLogn)` for sorting i think)

Comment: @sitsOnRedChair: No, it's not O(n^2) - because a lookup in a `HashSet` is O(1), not O(n).

Comment: If there are n elements in the set then it will do O(n) tests on l1.contains(i), and List.contains is O(n). This is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754881/what-is-the-time-and-space-complexity-of-method-retainall-when-used-on-hashsets. Am I missing something?

Comment: @sfjac: My code doesn't call l1.contains(i). It calls set.contains(i).

Comment: Was referring to the second snippet- I should have been more precise. `retainAll` will call `set.contains(l1)`.

Comment: @sfjac: Well where do you see the second snippet calling `List.contains`?

Comment: Sorry, should have peeked at my reference. The implementation of `retainAll` loops oner the elements in the set and calls `container.contains(element)` for each element in the set. If `container` is a list then that's O(n).

Comment: @sfjac: Ah, I see what you mean. That's easily fixed then, by just creating a new set... will edit.

Answer (score 5):

The usual way is to add each item from the first list to a `HashSet`, and then test each item in the second list for existence in that set:

```
Set<Integer> firstSet = new HashSet<Integer>(l1);
for (Integer i : l2) {
    if (firstSet.contains(i)) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```