# Efficient way to get indexes of matched items using Lists

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I've two lists A and B. I'd like to find out indexes of elements in A that match elements of listB. Something like this:

```
ArrayList listA = new ArrayList();
listA.add(1);listA.add(2);listA.add(3);listA.add(4);
ArrayList listB = new ArrayList();
listB.add(2);listB.add(4);
ArrayList listC = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0; i<listB.size();i++) {
   int element = listB.get(i);
   for(int j=0; j<listA.size(); j++) {
      if(listA.get(j) == element) listC.add(j);
   }
}
```

I guess that's one ugly way to doing it. What is the best way to finding all the indexes of A that match all elements in B? I believe there exists a method called containsAll in collections api - don't think it returns matching indexes.

Comment: Can either list contain duplicate values?

Comment: Is there a reason Set's won't work?  http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: I'd guess they can't ..contain duplicate values.

Comment: I need indexes of the elements - using a Set is going to be same as using List?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you had to use an `ArrayList`, you could create a `HashSet` from the `ArrayList`.  This would make the call to `contains` O(1).  It would take O(n) to create the `HastSet`.  If you could start with a `HashSet`, that would be best.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    List listA = new ArrayList();
    listA.add(1);
    listA.add(2);
    listA.add(3);
    listA.add(4);
    List listB = new ArrayList();
    listB.add(2);
    listB.add(4);
    Set hashset = new HashSet(listA);

    for(int i = 0; i < listB.size(); i++) 
    {
        if(hashset.contains(listB.get(i))) 
        {
            listC.add(i);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: contains() is not so efficient.

Comment: so.. there is no way to this other than a minimum complexity of O(n)?

Comment: looping through n elements in list A and looping through m elements in list B for each element in list A seems to be less efficient than O(n) to me.

Comment: looping through n elements in list A happens when you create a HashSet?

Comment: @DwB - contains for a HashSet is efficient, its O(1)

Comment: @Jay - You need to loop to create the HashSet and to Search through one of the ArrayLists.  You will only need to loop once if you start with the HashSet and not an ArrayList.

Comment: Are you sure that the complexity of creating a HashSet from an arraylist is O(n)?

Comment: @Jay - Yup (http://www.coderfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/java_collections_v2.pdf).  Add for a HashSet is O(1), but you do it n times.

Comment: if you do it n times at 0(1) - that is same as O(n), isn't it? So the total complexity would be O(n) + O(n)? Pardon my ignorance - I'm not good with algo complexity.

Comment: @Jay - That is correct.  If you start out with a HashSet, then you can reduce it to just O(n).  But using the way I did with copying the ArrayList to a HashSet and then searching is O(n) + O(n) as you mentioned.

Comment: btw, this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986757/efficient-way-to-do-contains-between-two-lists says the complexity would be O(n^2) and not O(n)+O(n)

Comment: @Jay - If you look at Jon Skeets comments in his answer, he says the same thing I did.  It's O(n) because the lookup in a HashSet is O(1).  This answer says the same thing mine does.  Turn one of the ArrayLists into a HashSet.

Comment: O(n^2) assumes table scan of list a and table scan list b for each element in list a.  This was my assumption, and (as indicated in comments above) is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The Guava libraries come with a method

```
"SetView com.google.common.collect.Sets.intersection(Set a, Set b)
```

that will give the elements contained in both sets, but not the indexes. Although it should be easy to get the indexes afterwards.

Comment: third party libraries for a simple thing as this?

Comment: @Jay, yes, that's Java... I can imagine writing a very straightforward line of LINQ if I were in C# world for a change...

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
List<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
listA.add(1);
listA.add(2);
listA.add(3);
listA.add(4);

List<Integer> listB = new ArrayList<Integer>();
listB.add(2);
listB.add(4);

List<Integer> listC = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for ( Integer item : listA ) {
    int index = listB.indexOf( item );
    if ( index >= 0 ) {
        listC.add(index);
    }
}
```

But this only works if **there is no repetition**, if there are repeated indexes you have to do it the way you did, navigating the full list.

**EDIT**

I thought you wanted the elements, not indexes, sets are not going to give you indexes, only the elements.

Comment: what is the time complexity of using contains() method here? Secondly, I need the indexes not the actual elements at these indexes.

Comment: **contains** is an O(n) operation.

Comment: that's linear complexity. What about finding indexes?

Comment: Updated answer and your question title to say **indexes** instead of matching items.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there's no duplicate values, why not use [ArrayList.indexOf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29)?

---

```
public final class ArrayListDemo {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        findIndices(createListA(), createListB());      
    }

    private static final List<Integer> createListA(){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(5);

        return list;
    }

    private static final List<Integer> createListB(){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(0);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);

        return list;
    }

    private static void findIndices(List<Integer> listA, List<Integer> listB){
        for(int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++){  
            // Get index of object in list b
            int index = listB.indexOf(listA.get(i));

            // Check for match
            if(index != -1){
                System.out.println("Found match:");
                System.out.println("List A index = " + i);
                System.out.println("List B index = " + index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Found match:
List A index = 1
List B index = 2
```

Comment: the `get` runs in constant time (i.e. O(1)) and `indexOf` runs in linear time (i.e. O(n)).

Comment: the for loop means - you'll be doing indexOf as many times as the number of elements in A  - Do you think SwDevMan81's answer below is more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

If list A and list B are sorted in the same order (I'll assume ascending, but descending works as well) this problem has an O(n) solution.  Below is some (informal, and untested) code.  When the loop exits, indexMap should contain the indices of every element in list A that match an element in list B and the index of the matched element in list B.

```
  int currentA;
  int currentB;
  int listAIndex = 0;
  int listBIndex = 0;
  Map<Integer, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

  currentA = listA.get(listAIndex);
  currentB = listB.get(listBIndex);
  while ((listAIndex < listA.length) && (listBIndex < listB.length))
  {
    if (currentA == currentB)
    {
      indexMap.put(listAIndex, listBIndex);
      ++listAIndex;
    }
    else if (currentA < currentB)
    {
      ++listAIndex;
    }
    else // if (currentA > currentB)
    {
      ++listBIndex;
    }
  }
```

Comment: if the lists are not sorted, I guess - the additional complexity involved in sorting would add up to the total complexity, wouldn't it?

Comment: The complexity becomes the least efficient of the sort vs O(n).  Usually that will mean the the complexity of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Apache CollectionUtils](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/CollectionUtils.html), there are plenty of options