# What is the time and space complexity of method retainAll when used on HashSets in Java?

Tags: java, big-o, hashset

For example in the code below:

```
public int commonTwo(String[] a, String[] b)
{
    Set common = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
    common.retainAll(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(b)));
    return common.size();
}
```

Comment: What's with the rawtype?

Comment: which rawtype are you talking about?

Comment: Nothing special just the usual habit of using run time polymorphism.

Comment: @Anirudh you misunderstand. You have a `Set` and not a `Set<String>`. This is a raw generic type and its use is **strongly** discouraged.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lets take a peruse at [the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/HashSet.java?av=f). The method `retainAll` is inherited from `AbstractCollection` and (at least in OpenJDK) looks like this:

```
public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (!c.contains(it.next())) {
            it.remove();
            modified = true;
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

There is one big this to note here, we loop over `this.iterator()` and call `c.contains`. So the time complexity is `n` calls to `c.contains` where `n = this.size()` and at most `n` calls to `it.remove()`.

This important thing is that the `contains` method is called on the *other* `Collection` and so the complexity is dependant upon the complexity of the other `Collection` `contains`.

So, whilst:

```
Set<String> common = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
common.retainAll(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(b)));
```

Would be `O(a.length)`, as `HashSet.contains` and `HashSet.remove` are both `O(1)` (amortized).

If you were to call

```
common.retainAll(Arrays.asList(b));
```

Then due to the `O(n)` `contains` on `Arrays.ArrayList` this would become `O(a.length * b.length)` - i.e. by spending `O(n)` copying the array to a `HashSet` you actually make the call to `retainAll` much faster.

As far as space complexity goes, no additional space (beyond the `Iterator`) is required by `retainAll`, but your invocation is actually quite expensive space-wise as you allocate two new `HashSet` implementations which are actually fully fledged `HashMap`.

Two further things can be noted:

1. There is no reason to allocate a `HashSet` from the elements in `a` - a cheaper collection that also has `O(1)` remove from the middle such as an `LinkedList` can be used. (cheaper in memory and also build time - a hash table is not built)
2. Your modifications are being lost as you create new collection instances and only return `b.size()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, regarding space complexity I think using HashSets would result in increase in hashing as the size of the Method Parameters increase. Don't you think with respect to the size of input the method's space complexity increases linearly or of O(n)?

Comment: @Anirudh as I said _but your invocation is actually quite expensive space-wise as you allocate two new `HashSet` implementations_. These are really quite memory intensive due to all the satellite data. The `retainAll` method itself would use `O(1)` memory I reckon.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation can be found in the `java.util.AbstractCollection` class. The way it is implemented looks like this:

```
public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(c);
        boolean modified = false;
        Iterator<E> it = iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            if (!c.contains(it.next())) {
                it.remove();
                modified = true;
            }
        }
        return modified;
    }
```

So it will iterate everything in your `common` set and check if the collection that was passed as a parameter contains this element.

In your case both are `HashSet`s, thus it will be O(n), as contains should be O(1) amortized and iterating over your `common` set is O(n).

One improvement you can make, is simply not copy `a` into a new `HashSet`, because it will be iterated anyway you can keep a list.

Comment: You last comment doesn't work because the array `a` would be modified by the calls to `it.remove()` if it weren't for the fact that `Arrays.ArrayList` doesn't support `remove()`. And `Arrays.ArrayList.size()` always returns the length of the wrapped array.