# Best way to make conjunctions and disjunctions over a collection in java

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist

What's the most efficient way to create an `and` and `or`methods over two ArrayLists?

```
//not coded in java 

HashSet<String> first  = {"hello", "to", "you"}
HashSet<String> second = {"hello", "to", "me"}

HashSet<String> and = and(first, second) = {"hello", "to"}
HashSet<String> or = or(first, second) = {"hello", "to", "you", "me"}
```

I need to implement those two methods (pretty easy) but I would need to do it efficiently, because I will `and` and `or` over collections with hundreds of Strings. Any tip?

Comment: [`java.util.set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) offers an `addAll` (union, or 'or' method) and a `retainAll` (intersection, or 'and' method). So perhaps you're best off using `Set`s that support those operations if you can manage it, or else converting your lists to sets if it's not too expensive, and leveraging what already exists.

Comment: Do you want to treat the lists as sets? Are you guaranteed that elements will appear only once? If not, what would you want to happen with (say) `{"a", "b", "a"}` and `{"b", "a", "b"}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid confusion I'll call the methods `intersection` and `union` as the meanings of `AND` and `OR` are a little ambiguous.

There is a [`retainAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) method on `Set` that will do the job of the intersection. You need to take heed of my caveats in [another answer (of mine) on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24755224/2071828).

There is an [`addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll(java.util.Collection,%20T...)) method on `Collection` that will do the job of union.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final Set<String> first = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("hello", "to", "you"));
    final Set<String> second = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("hello", "to", "me"));

    System.out.println(intersection(first, second));
    System.out.println(union(first, second));

}

public static Set<String> intersection(final Set<String> first, final Set<String> second) {
    final Set<String> copy = new HashSet<>(first);
    copy.retainAll(second);
    return copy;
}

public static Set<String> union(final Set<String> first, final Set<String> second) {
    final Set<String> copy = new HashSet<>(first);
    copy.addAll(second);
    return copy;
}
```

Note use usage of `Set` rather than `List`. This serves two purposes:

1. `Set` has `O(1)` `contains` as opposed to `O(n)` for a `List`. This helps in the intersection case.
2. `Set` guarantees uniqueness. This helps in the union case.

Also note that I copy the collections before carrying out the operations - as Java passes references by value not copying would cause the original collection to be changed.

If you need to preserve order, you will need to use a `LinkedHashSet` as a `HashSet` has no order.

Comment: Your link to your other answer is mistakenly a link to the `Set` javadoc.

Comment: retainAll is the 'and' and addAll is the 'or'. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I used the more traditional usage - in your usage I have it backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set for that, just need to cast.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

And use its methods to do that

Comment: This isn't English this is programming - cast has a [very specific meaning](http://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-cast/).

Answer (score 0):

You want to make the intersection and the union of two ArrayLists.
I think that this is a duplicate question.
I suggest to take a look at this thread:
[Intersection and union of ArrayLists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283047/intersection-and-union-of-arraylists-in-java)