# Rearranging one string to another in Java

Tags: java, string, character

I am trying to find whether a part of given string A can be or can not be rearranged to given string B (Boolean output).
Since the algorithm must be at most O(n), to ease it, I used stringA.retainAll(stringB), so now I know string A and string B consist of the same set of characters and now the whole task smells like regex.
And .. reading about regex, I might be now *having two problems*(c).
The question is, do I potentially face a risk of getting O(infinity) by using regex or its more efficient to use StreamAPI with the purpose of finding whether each character of string A has enough duplicates to cover each of character of string B?  Let alone regex syntax is not easy to read and build.
As of now, I can't use sorting (any sorting is at least n*log(n)) nor hashsets and the likes (as it eliminates duplicates in both strings).
Thank you.

Comment: Acc to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754881/what-is-the-time-and-space-complexity-of-method-retainall-when-used-on-hashsets retainAll is O(n)

Comment: Only on `HashSet` but you say you can't use hashes.

Comment: @talex Exactly, using hashes eliminates number of occurrences for each character. In case string B has a character that occurs more than corresponding character in string B, Hashset will return true, but it is actually false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap<Character,Integer>` to count the number of occurrences of each character of the first `String`. That would take linear time.

Then, for each `Character` of the second `String`, find if it's in the `HashMap` and decrement the counter (if it's still positive). This will also take linear time, and if you manage to decrement the counters for all the characters of the second `String`, you succeed.

Comment: Thank you, Eran. Does this mean I compare each character in string B with each element of the HashMap? If so, isn't that O(n^2)?

Comment: @Shved no, for each character of B you call `Integer count = map.get(B.charAt(i));` which takes O(1) time (and if `count` is not null and > 0, you call `map.put(B.charAt(i),count-1)`, which also takes `O(1)` time). Therefore the total time will be linear.